# How to change username color in chat program (VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I am building a chat program which uses a server and a client. Now I have another idea: a user should be able to select his user color and the messages he sends would have his name in that color. I searched all over the web, but couldn't find a solution. How to implement this?

[image: Preview of form design]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not terrible, in fact I like it, but instead of posting an image, which is not really useful, you should provide some additional detail about the implementation. What is the object shown in the low part of the window? Is it a TextBox?

Comment: It's a RichTextBox. If it's helpful here's the link to this program http://www.mediafire.com/download/a9h6zmsq4djdvbe/Chat.zip (287Kb)

Comment: Another general advice: post only **relevant** parts of your code, and do it **in the question** formatting it as `code`. External links should be used only when there is no other option. This greatly improves the chance of getting an answer, because the number of people that would answer the question is greater than the number of people willing to download a ZIP archive, open it and analyze all the code (and in this case, other useless project files) you've stuffed inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a `RichTextBox` rather than a regular `TextBox`.  For more advanced functionality, you could create a custom `UserControl` which represents a single chat message.  The custom control could have a property that allows you to change the color for that message (and user image, and anything else you want to add).  You could load any number of them into a `FlowLayoutPanel` (one per message).  Alternatively, you may want to consider using WPF rather than WinForms.